# Responsive design - problems with DIVs when resizing browser

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm in the process of turning my currently fixed width site into a responsive site which can be viewed at: http://www.byfrequency.co.uk/demo

I've created the CSS framework and applied the relevant media queries (with the help of Gridpak) so no problems there. The problem I'm getting is when I resize the browser my divs change position and end up creating a flickering effect. This only seems to occur between my set widths of 768px and 1080px.

I've no idea why this is happening and how to solve the problem so not able to copy and paste the relevant bits of code. Would really appreciate some help and guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flickering is coming from the few elements that jump from the left side to the right side at certain widths. Because of the way browsers round things, the two halves of the row *above* the jumping elements **do not have the same height**. When the right side of the above row becomes shorter by 1 pixel, the jumping element moves up into that space. Its `float: left;` property fits it on the right side of the big ‘taller by 1 pixel’ block on the left.

To prevent the jumping, try adding `clear: left;` to the jumping elements at the problematic widths. (In my test, adding this to the *.five* element at *line 761* prevented it from jumping. I tried it there in your “Medium” media query because your layout only needs it at `min-width: 768px` and wider.)

Ultimately, thanks to browser rounding, you will still see 1px height mismatches between these row halves, but big issue will be prevented by clearing the floats in the problem areas.

Comment: Hey Joel, thanks for the comprehensive explanation and solution. Really good to understand why this is happening! I'll give it a try and update you with how I get on.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer; it was fun to check out your site. One other thing I'd point you to is Foldy: https://github.com/davatron5000/Foldy960. It's a great “starting point” for coding your own responsive sites; I learned some great techniques from it.

(Related – I made a Google Doc that explains the math behind Foldy, and how to give it a 12-grid base: http://tiny.cc/foldymath)

Comment: I managed to solve the jumping DIVs with your help so thank you very much! Also thanks for checking out my site. As a designer, its actually been a lot of fun being able to code my own responsive site. Many designers use templated sites like Squarespace now so at least I can proudly say that I've crafted my site with my own hands!